# How do you write this covariance equation in matlab without any loops

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, covariance-matrix

How would you implement the following in Matlab without loops:
$$
\Sigma = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\mathbf x_i - \mu_{yi})(\mathbf x_i - \mu_{yi})^T
$$
Where $\mathbf x \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is your input matrix, $\mathbf y \in \{0,1\}$ is your label column vector. Additionally, you need to have already calculated parameters $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ which are the means of $\mathbf x$ for samples of class 0 and 1 (according to vector $\mathbf y$). The tricky part is $\mu_{yi}$. In the equation, you cannot simply multiply the input with its mean, since $\mu_{yi}$ is a conditional mean. If class of $\mathbf x_i$ is 0, then $\mu_{yi}=\mu_0$, otherwise $\mu_{yi}=\mu_1$.

How can you do this elegantly in Matlab without loops and checking for $y_i$ at every sample?

Comment: This is a MATLAB programming question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sexy ideas are [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and [bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

```
y1_logical = y==1;
u1 = mean(X(y1_logical,:));
u2 = mean(X(~y1_logical,:));

X_demean = zeros(size(X));
X_demean(y1_logical,:)  = bsxfun(@minus, X(y1_logical,:), u1);
X_demean(~y1_logical,:) = bsxfun(@minus, X(~y1_logical,:), u2);

Sigma = X_demean' * X_demean / m;
```

Comment: FYI: In 2016b, Matlab **finally** introduced ["auto-bsxfun"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html#bu90xzg-8) (a.k.a. "broadcasting"). "In MATLAB® R2016b and later, you can directly use operators instead of bsxfun, since the operators independently support implicit expansion of arrays with compatible sizes."

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Crazy!

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks! How can I move the question to so?